# Upgrading from Spring 2.5 to 4.x made Spring Security not working

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm updating dependencies from a legacy spring project on 2.5.6 to 4.1.6. I may, when working, try to upgrade to lastest Spring 4 version (I know Spring it's not giving more maintenance to Spring4.x, but we have to stay at J7 for some other issues).

So project was Spring 2.5.6 and completely configured with web.xml (just some @autowired and that kind of stuff). It's using AOP, Spring Security 2.0.5 and Hibernate 3.3.1, and working correctly.

I've been able to update dependencies and now project compiles, builds and deploys fine in a Tomcat7. Everything but Spring Security.

This is the error I'm facing

```
[WARN] Nested in org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0' while setting constructor argument with key [4]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0' while setting bean property 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#e2508ff' of type [org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'eraseCredentialsAfterAuthentication'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#e2508ff': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy168.isEraseCredentialsAfterAuthentication():
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy168.isEraseCredentialsAfterAuthentication()
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1670)
at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.prepare(MethodInvoker.java:174)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(MethodInvokingFactoryBean.java:103)
```

I read [here (SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25216793/spring-security-and-aop-issue) someone who apparently faced the same problem and it was related to AOP. Here is my relevant application-Context.xml config where you can see I'm not having that problem (or at least that's what I think) of too relaxed pointcut.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.company.my.project" />
<context:annotation-config />
<!--Hibernate and JPA-->
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" lazy-init="true">
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:${env}/META-INF/persistence.xml"/> 
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
<import resource="applicationContext-Manager.xml" />
<import resource="applicationContext-DAO.xml" /> 
<import resource="applicationContext-common-resources.xml" />
<import resource="applicationContext-Business.xml" />
<!--works without this line-->
<import resource="applicationContext-security.xml" />
<import resource="applicationContext-RestBeans.xml" />    
<import resource="applicationContext-RestClient.xml" />
<import resource="applicationContext-reports.xml" />
<import resource="applicationContext-dispatcherServletBeans.xml" />
<import resource="applicationContext-Quartz.xml" />

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" lazy-init="true"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" lazy-init="true"/>

<bean id="myTxManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" lazy-init="true">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="myTxManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="get*,count*" read-only="true" />
        <tx:method name="*"
            rollback-for="com.company.my.project.commons.exception.MyException" />
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="myPointCut"
        expression="execution( com.company.my.project.server.spring.manager..*.*(..))" />
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="myPointCut" />
</aop:config>
```

And this is my complete Spring-security config file (trying to simplify it the most I could to get where the error is coming from, in production I'll be using a Custom Authentication Provider)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd"><sec:http auto-config="true" />
    <sec:authentication-manager >
        <sec:authentication-provider>
            <sec:user-service>
                <sec:user name="bill"  password="abc123"  authorities="ROLE_USER" />
                <sec:user name="admin" password="root123" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
                <sec:user name="dba"   password="root123" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_DBA" />
            </sec:user-service>
        </sec:authentication-provider>
    </sec:authentication-manager>
    </beans>
```

Can anyone give me any clue? It's been now 3 days since I faced this and I'm completely stuck on this point :(

EDIT: Added pom.xml

```
<springVersion>4.1.6.RELEASE</springVersion>
<springSecurityVersion>4.0.2.RELEASE</springSecurityVersion>
<slf4jVersion>1.5.2</slf4jVersion>
<jersey.version>1.18.1</jersey.version>
<jackson.mapper.version>1.9.2</jackson.mapper.version>
<jUnit.version>4.5</jUnit.version>
<activemq-spring.version>5.13.0</activemq-spring.version>
<hibernate.version>3.3.1.GA</hibernate.version>
<hibernate.annotations.version>3.4.0.GA</hibernate.annotations.version>
    

<!--  Spring security-->    
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    <version>${springSecurityVersion}</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>${springSecurityVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>${springSecurityVersion}</version>
</dependency>

<!-- SLF4J -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>${slf4jVersion}</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    <optional>false</optional>
</dependency>   

<!-- Spring -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
    <version>${springVersion}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>${springVersion}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId> 
    <version>${springVersion}</version>
    <type>jar</type> 
    <optional>false</optional> 
</dependency> 

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    <version>${springVersion}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>${springVersion}</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Jackson -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.mapper.version}</version>
</dependency>

<!--Active MQ-->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
    <artifactId>activemq-spring</artifactId>
    <version>${activemq-spring.version}</version>
</dependency>


<!-- Hibernate -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    <optional>false</optional>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.annotations.version}</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    <optional>false</optional>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.annotations.version}</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    <optional>false</optional>
</dependency>


<!-- Jersey -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-spring</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>    
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Edit: Added fullstrackce ([here](https://pastebin.com/P0eqzkCq), couldn't paste it here due to charlimit) and mvn dependency:tree

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] The project com.company:my_project:war:5.4.0 uses prerequisites which is only intended for maven-plugin projects but not for non maven-plugin projects. For such purposes you should use the maven-enforcer-plugin. See https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireMavenVersion.html
[INFO] 
[INFO] ---------------------< com.company:my_project>----------------------
[INFO] Building my_project5.4.0
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ my_project---
[INFO] com.company:my_project:war:5.4.0
[INFO] +- javax.persistence:persistence-api:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.4:compile
[INFO] +- com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- xpp3:xpp3_min:jar:1.1.4c:compile
[INFO] +- cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.6.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.6.0:compile
[INFO] +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.14:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.2:compile
[INFO] +- javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-annotations:jar:3.4.0.GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:ejb3-persistence:jar:1.0.2.GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:3.1.0.GA:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:3.3.0.SP1:compile
[INFO] |     \- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-jms:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-messaging:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-instrument:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-instrument-tomcat:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- javax.jms:jms:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.extjs:gxt:jar:2.3.0-gwt22:compile
[INFO] +- com.company:commons_dependencies:jar:4.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.company.projects:projects-clients:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:jar:2.1.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- c3p0:c3p0:jar:0.9.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.company.projects.status:status-api:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.log4j:com.springsource.org.apache.log4j:jar:1.2.15:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.sun.mail:javax.mail:jar:1.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-net:commons-net:jar:3.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-text:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.spy:spymemcached:jar:2.12.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- de.oscillation.gwt:goda-time:jar:0.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.sonar-plugins:sonar-ant-task:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bull.javamelody:javamelody-core:jar:1.81.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.jrobin:jrobin:jar:1.5.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jasypt:jasypt-springsecurity3:jar:1.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.activemq:activemq-all:jar:5.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jvnet:mimepull:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.google.zxing:core:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:3.4.0.GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javassist:javassist:jar:3.4.GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.gwt:gwt-user:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.0.0.GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:sources:1.0.0.GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.gwt:gwt-servlet:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.5.2:runtime
[INFO] |  +- com.google.code.gwt-log:gwt-log:jar:2.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:4.0.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:4.0.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:4.0.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.activemq:activemq-spring:jar:5.13.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.xbean:xbean-spring:jar:3.18:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.activemq:activemq-broker:jar:5.13.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.activemq:activemq-client:jar:5.13.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jms_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.fusesource.hawtbuf:hawtbuf:jar:1.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-j2ee-management_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.activemq:activemq-openwire-legacy:jar:5.13.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.activemq:activemq-pool:jar:5.13.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.activemq:activemq-jms-pool:jar:5.13.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jta_1.0.1B_spec:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-pool2:jar:2.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.googlecode:hibernate-memcached:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.1:compile
[INFO] +- opensymphony:ognl:jar:2.6.11:compile
[INFO] +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] +- commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:1.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.drools:drools-compiler:jar:5.1.0.M1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.drools:drools-core:jar:5.1.0.M1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.drools:drools-api:jar:5.1.0.M1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.antlr:antlr-runtime:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jdt:core:jar:3.4.2.v_883_R34x:compile
[INFO] |  +- janino:janino:jar:2.5.15:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.mvel:mvel2:jar:2.0.12:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-math:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:jar:1.18.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.18.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-json:jar:1.18.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.3-1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0-2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-jaxrs:jar:1.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-xc:jar:1.9.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:jar:1.18.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-servlet:jar:1.18.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-multipart:jar:1.18.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jvnet.mimepull:mimepull:jar:1.9.3:compile
[INFO] +- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.2.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-io:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.jasypt:jasypt:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.ibm.icu:icu4j:jar:3.4.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:jar:1.5.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.ant:ant:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- jline:jline:jar:0.9.94:compile
[INFO] +- net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:jar:4.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.lowagie:itext:jar:2.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk14:jar:138:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:jar:138:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.bouncycastle:bctsp-jdk14:jar:1.38:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:jar:1.38:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk14:jar:1.38:compile
[INFO] |  +- jfree:jcommon:jar:1.0.15:compile
[INFO] |  +- jfree:jfreechart:jar:1.0.12:compile
[INFO] |  +- eclipse:jdtcore:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.castor:castor:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- ar.com.fdvs:DynamicJasper:jar:4.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:jar:3.6:compile
[INFO] \- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:jar:3.6:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO]    |  \- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO]    \- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.790 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-02-16T10:29:12+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Did you upgrade Spring **or** Spring Security or both?

Comment: Upgraded both Spring and Spring Security. Added pom.xml dependencies on post.

Comment: `Activemq-spring` brings in Spring 4.1.8 (also why aren't you just upgrading to the latest 4.1.x version instead of some older version?). Jersey 1.18.1 pulls in Spring 2.5 and its dependencies. That being said I would strongly suggest to use the latest Spring Security from the 4.0.x line instead of some intermediate version and use the latest Spring 4.1.x. TO see if dependencies are the culprit run `mvn dependency:tree` and see if things have different versions. Finally please post the **full stacktrace** instead of the snippet you have now.

Comment: That's why I added exclusions on the pom.xml. I was first trying to get it at same Spring versions than other working projects (so I know the config works) and then upgrade all of them. I thought it's more a web.xml or Spring config problem than a version one. Maybe some missing annotations, maybe a custom filter malfunctioning on new config, something like that. But I'm completely lost, so I fully appreciate your help!